# Embed Safari's Webinspector in Browserwindow as default

Tags: macos, browser, safari, settings

Is there an attribute (in com.apple.Safari.plist?) to embed the Webinspector when it is opened (via [CMD]+[ALT]+[I] / [Developer]->[Show Webinformation]) as default?

> Mac OSX Lion 10.7, Safari: 5.1

Since i updated, the Inspector won't stay popped-in.
At the time of SnowLeopard, i might have configured the SafariDefaults, but i already read the defaults via

> default read com.apple.Safari

and didn't find a relevant attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a known bug and has been fixed in the latest build of WebKit.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65493

Also confirmed it myself with Nightly Build revision 94958. Hopefully it will make it into a new version of Safari soon!